# Symfony2 gedmo Soft Deleteable relation retrieval not working properly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, soft-delete

I am using the soft-Deletable  extension and all is working fine, except for 1 thing.

When I am doing the following equals true (Pseudocode):

```
null == $fooRepository->findByCriteria('criteria to find deleted entity');
```

But the following equals false

```
null == $otherEntity->getDeletedFooEntity()
```

There for when I do this

```
if ($otherEntity->getDeletedFooEntity() != null)
{
    $var = $otherEntity->getDeletedFooEntity()->getAnyProperty();
}
```

I am getting a Server 500 Error: Entity was not found

How can I make it so it returns null? Or am I doing it wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Adam, on your code, it's not really clear what getDeletedFooEntity do, because afaik, it's not a symfony nor doctrine-extensions basic behaviour or helper.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the 500 error, you can modify your code as such:

```
if ($otherEntity->getDeletedFooEntity() instanceOf Foo) {
    $var = $otherEntity->getDeletedFooEntity()->getAnyProperty();
}
```

where Foo is the class that is supposed to be returned by the "getDeletedFooEntity" method.

Answer (score 0):

Gedmo has a problem if you're using unique indexes on deleted entities. You can avoid this by changing the values when soft-deleting entities. Here you have more details on how to do this, in an article I wrote: http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/01/09/symfony2-gedmo-softdeletable-doctrine-entities-with-unique-index-columns/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this is by no means a thorough answer, it is not a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225371/179335) either @worldofjr.

Comment: @CarrieKendall You should go to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to raise issues like this.